# What kind of furniture cover(s) do I need for my sectional?

Tags: furniture

I have a very uniquely shaped sectional, and I need to get furniture covers for it so that my cats will not scratch it up. Picture below.

What kind of furniture covers do I need for this?  We have tried a sofa and loveseat combination, but it leaves a bare spot on the single seat 'lounge' portion, and a chaise-style sectional specific cover set also did not work.  [image]

Comment: Use a material that cat’s claws can’t get through or get one of those cat play toys come scratch post etc

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not actually looking for the material I need - I need to know what *kind* of covers I need - none of the ones I've tried thus far have actually fit the entire sectional.